# Convert XML to JSON based on xsi:type in JAVA

Tags: java, json, xml

I need to write a program in JAVA to convert XML into JSON based on the xsd types declared in the XML. For example, if the XML string is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<student xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <age xsi:type="xs:integer">11</age>
    <id xsi:type="xs:string">12</id>
    <name xsi:type="xs:string">JavaInterviewPoint</name>
</student>
```

Then the JSON will be:

```
{
  student: {
     age: 11,
     id: "12",
     name: "JavaInterviewPoint"
  }
}
```

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: You can use `Jackson 2`: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: Can you please share sample code for doing this or any other specific information to point me about this to the right direction?